How do I speed up selection of a large number of features
I'm looking for ways to speed up selection of a large number of features (10k+) from a list of attribute values.
I'm developing a plugin to trace a pipe network, and select the tranversed pipes. The pipe 'graph' is stored as a LineString layer with PIPE_ID, START_NODE and END_NODE attributes. I have solved the problem of finding PIPE_IDs for the tranversed pipes using a cached graph. The bottleneck appears to be finding the feature IDs of features to select.
After a bit of noodling (see below), I'm left with this:
    no_attr_request = (
        QgsFeatureRequest()
        .setFilterExpression(expression)
        .setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)
        .setSubsetOfAttributes([])
    )
    ids = [
        f.id()
        for f in layer.getFeatures(request=no_attr_request) 
        if f['PIPE_ID'] in attr_list
    ]
    layer.selectByIds(ids)

Is there anywhere left to improve?
These are other approaches I tried:

Select from an expression string like so: f'"PIPE_ID" in {tuple(pipe_ids)}'. However, I am concerned about the expression getting too long. Therefore, I have tried combining selections with slices of the full list:

for i in range(0, len(attr_list), page_limit):
      result_slice = attr_list[i:i+page_limit]
      expression = f"\"PIPE_ID\" in {tuple(result_slice)!s}"
      layer.selectByExpression(expression=expression,behavior=Qgis.SelectBehavior.AddToSelection)


Retrieve the features via expression, but get a list of ids to use on a single selection call like `layer.selectByIds(ids). Again, requires pagination when target number gets high.

I optimised where I could, but I don't think a long expression string is feasible. The limit is somewhere between 1k and 10k entries in the target tuple (~8 characters per entry + quotes and comma).
I have timed the approaches (code below):

Option 1 appears to take 0.9s per selection by expression call.
Option 2 appears to take the same amount of time to retrieve the features as Option 1, and selecting by ID is very fast.
Evaluating over the full layer is time consuming but faster.

Full test code:
import random
import time

from qgis.core import (
    Qgis,
    QgsExpression,
    QgsFeatureRequest,
    QgsVectorLayer,
)

sample_sizes = [500, 1000]

layer: QgsVectorLayer = iface.activeLayer()
assert 'PIPE_ID' in [field.name() for field in layer.fields()]
assert 'START_NODE' in [field.name() for field in layer.fields()]

single_attr_request = (
    QgsFeatureRequest()
    .setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)
    .setSubsetOfAttributes(['PIPE_ID'], fields=layer.fields())
)
all_features = list(layer.getFeatures(request=single_attr_request))

timing_subop = []
timing_op = []
current_time = time.time()

for sample_size in sample_sizes:
    # page_limits = [pl for pl in sample_sizes if pl <= sample_size]
    # current_time = time.time()

    # for page_limit in page_limits:
    #     # Test setup 1: by expression
    #     layer.removeSelection()
    #     rand_features = random.sample(all_features, sample_size)
    #     attr_list = [f['PIPE_ID'] for f in rand_features]
    #     timing_subop.append(f'time taken: {time.time() - current_time}, {page_limit=}, {sample_size=}, by expression: setup')
    #     current_time = time.time()

    #     # Test procedure 1: by expression
    #     timing_op.append((time.time(), 0.0, page_limit, sample_size, 'start procedure: by expression'))

    #     for i in range(0, len(attr_list), page_limit):
    #         result_slice = attr_list[i:i+page_limit]
    #         expression = f'"PIPE_ID" in {tuple(result_slice)!s}'
    #         layer.selectByExpression(expression=expression, behavior=Qgis.SelectBehavior.AddToSelection)
    #         timing_subop.append(f'time taken: {time.time() - current_time}, {page_limit=}, {sample_size=}, by expression: select {i}')
    #         current_time = time.time()

    #     timing_op.append((time.time(), time.time() - timing_op[-1][0], page_limit, sample_size, 'by expression'))

    #     # Test setup 2: by id
    #     layer.removeSelection()
    #     rand_features = random.sample(all_features, sample_size)
    #     attr_list = [f['PIPE_ID'] for f in rand_features]
    #     timing_subop.append(f'time taken: {time.time() - current_time}, {page_limit=}, {sample_size=}, by id: setup')
    #     current_time = time.time()

    #     # Test procedure 2: by id
    #     timing_op.append((time.time(), 0.0, page_limit, sample_size, 'start procedure: by id'))

    #     ids = []
    #     for i in range(0, len(attr_list), page_limit):
    #         result_slice = attr_list[i:i+page_limit]
    #         expression = f'"PIPE_ID" in {tuple(result_slice)!s}'
    #         no_attr_request = (
    #             QgsFeatureRequest()
    #             .setFilterExpression(expression)
    #             .setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)
    #             .setSubsetOfAttributes([])
    #         )
    #         features_slice = layer.getFeatures(request=no_attr_request)
    #         ids += [f.id() for f in features_slice]
    #         timing_subop.append(f'time taken: {time.time() - current_time}, {page_limit=}, {sample_size=}, by id: get ids {i}')
    #         current_time = time.time()

    #     layer.selectByIds(ids)
    #     timing_subop.append(f'time taken: {time.time() - current_time}, {page_limit=}, {sample_size=}, by id: select by ids')
    #     current_time = time.time()

    #     timing_op.append((time.time(), time.time() - timing_op[-1][0], page_limit, sample_size, 'end procedure: by id'))

    # Test setup 3: by id
    layer.removeSelection()
    rand_features = random.sample(all_features, sample_size)
    attr_list = [f['PIPE_ID'] for f in rand_features]
    timing_subop.append(f'time taken: {time.time() - current_time}, {sample_size=}, setup by iterator')
    current_time = time.time()

    # Test procedure 3: by id
    timing_op.append((time.time(), 0.0, sample_size, 'start procedure: by iterator'))

    ids = [
        f.id()
        for f in layer.getFeatures(request=single_attr_request)
        if f['PIPE_ID'] in attr_list
    ]
    timing_subop.append(f'time taken: {time.time() - current_time}, {sample_size=}, iterate layer by iterator')
    current_time = time.time()

    layer.selectByIds(ids)
    timing_subop.append(f'time taken: {time.time() - current_time}, {sample_size=}, finish by iterator')
    current_time = time.time()

    timing_op.append((time.time(), time.time() - timing_op[-1][0], sample_size, 'end procedure: by iterator'))

print('\n'.join(timing_subop))
print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, line[1:])) for line in timing_op if line[1] != 0))


Reference layer used had 300k features, actual layers will have <500k

Can't you have an indexed attribute "tranversed" with boolean values yes/no?

I suggest first considering @user30184's comment about simply using a field to indicate whether the pipe is tranverse or not. However, if you must do it using only the PIPE_ID you can try the following.
Instead of creating a list of the getFeatures() call, you can create a dictionary. The "PIPE_ID" can be the key and the features IDs the values.
It looks something like this:
{'pipe id 1': 1, 'pipe id 2': 2, ...: ...}

This way, you already have the associated ID and you do not need to call getFeatures a second time and loop through to make the QgsFeatureRequest for the IDs.
Here is a code sample to get a random selection, similar to your test:
import random 

lyr = iface.activeLayer() 

# generate a dictionary of {PIPE_ID: feature id},  {key: value} pairs for all features using dictionary comprehension
# features with a NULL PIPE_ID are skipped
feat_dict = {f['PIPE_ID']: f.id() for f in lyr.getFeatures() if f['PIPE_ID']}

# get a random sample of PIPE_IDs
sample_size = 10000
rand_pipe_ids = random.sample(list(feat_dict.keys()), sample_size)

# query the dictionary to get a list of feature IDs 
ids_to_select = [feat_dict.get(pipe_id) for pipe_id in rand_pipe_ids]

lyr.selectByIds(ids_to_select)


To speed up the graph traversing, the graph is stored as dict. I considered this but assumed the fid is not consistent for a given layer. Is it always the same? If so, I could totally use it as the id in the graph

Are you asking whether the ID is tied to a feature in a layer? If so, yes. Each feature in the layer has a persistent ID. This remains the same on closing and re-opening the project etc. Deleting a feature will not reassign IDs, the particular ID associated with the feature will be removed.

What about a layer from the same source in a different project?
